# Access VBA SQL Run-time error 3134 INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a VBA code for an Access 2013, and i want to run INSERT INTO, but when i try to run it, it keeps drop the messeage "Run-time error 3134  Syntax error in 'INSERT INTO'".
There is my code:

```
      Private Sub Parancsgomb35_Click()
Set valamiami = Me.Szöveg29
Dim neveteke As String
Me.KombináltLista27.SetFocus
neveteke = Me.KombináltLista27.Value
Set db_number = Me.Szöveg15
Dim sql_cucc As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT sarzsszám, cikkszam, me, afa, behozatali, netto FROM torzslapok WHERE neve='" & neveteke & "'")

While Not rs.EOF
Set afaka = rs.Fields("afa")
Set sarzsszamka = rs.Fields("sarzsszám")
Set mennka = rs.Fields("me")
Set cikkszamka = rs.Fields("cikkszam")
Set behozatalika = rs.Fields("behozatali")
Set nettoka = rs.Fields("netto")
sql_cucc = "INSERT INTO BE-ALPHAVET(neve, afa, behozatali, netto, db, sarzsszám, cikkszam, me) VALUES('" & neveteke & "','" & afaka & "','" & behozatalika & "','" & nettoka & "','" & db_number & "','" & sarzsszamka & "','" & cikkszamka & "','" & mennka & "');"
CurrentDb.Execute sql_cucc
Wend

End Sub

valamiami = DATE like yyyy.mm.dd
neveteke = STRING
KombináltLista27 = STRING (COMBINE LIST with ine select only)
db_number = INTERGER
sql_cucc = STRING
afaka = INTEGER
sarzsszamka = STRING
mennka = STRING
cikkszamka = STRING
behozatalika = INTEGER
nettoka = INTEGER
```

I read a lot of forum, but a didn't find any answer..
Can somebody explain for me what is the problem?
Thanks and love!

Comment: Maybe you should output the value of `sql_cucc` before you execute it so you can see the whole statement. One of your variables may have a single quote or something that's screwing up your `insert` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `INSERT` starts as:

```
INSERT INTO BE-ALPHAVET(neve, afa, behozatali, netto, db,
                        sarzsszám, cikkszam, me)
```

The `-` is interpreted as a minus sign.  You need to escape the table name:

```
INSERT INTO [BE-ALPHAVET](neve, afa, behozatali, netto, db,
                          sarzsszám, cikkszam, me)
```

Or, better yet, change it to an underscore (`_`) so you don't have to escape the name at all.

Comment: Thanks! You are the best! That's not like in php MySql.. .:D